# System processes like DllHost.exe and WmiPrvSe.exe are slowing down Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, performance, process

Windows 7 started to work slower and I used Autoruns, ProcExp and ProcMon to look at what was causing the issue. I found that it happened when DllHost.exe and WmiPrvSe.exe were running, but I'm not sure if these are causing the problem. But every time I stopped those tasks, the OS worked normally.

Now the same problem exists in Windows 8. Also, the HDD is being used 100 percent.

I've done some research in Win 8 and Sysinternals' Process Explorer told me that those processes are mainly run by svchost.exe:

```
D:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k DcomLaunch
```

This runs DllHost and WmiPrvSe with these commands:

```
D:\Windows\system32\DllHost.exe /Processid:{3EB3C877-1F16-487C-9050-104DBCD66683}
D:\Windows\system32\WmiPrvSe.exe
```

Note: Processid is not always the same

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: why so certain its the above causing the problem? have you tried sys internals tools like autoruns?

Comment: @Logman Yes. and not only Autoruns, but also ProcExp, ProcMon,...

Answer (score 0):

First update your Windows.

I would suggest you to download Process Hacker from hear: [Download Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/)

Now you can see all the processes running on your system. Also with right click you can search the Internet for more information on the process running on your computer. There is also a nice Graph where you can see what processes take how much CPU.

The dllhost.exe file manages DLL based applications. This program is important for the stable and secure running of your computer and should not be terminated. Without WmiPrvSE, users will not receive notifications when errors occur.

svchost.exe should not be stopped, also i would suggest not to stop WmiPrvSe. But if it uses to much CPU look at this Microsoft link [hear](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1157). (not sure if for Windows 8)

Hit on your Keyboard Windows-Logo+R and write services.msc, from hear you might set some services from Automatic to Manual, which means that they will start only when needed, but be careful don't  mess with a service if you don't know what it does. Check also msconfig.

At the end if nothing helps, your computer might be infected. Try to check your computer with antivirus.

If nothing helps download and run [HijackThis](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1157) then post the log here. It'll give us a decent idea of whats running and what could be hogging all your memory/cpu.

Hear are also some interesting threads on Super User:

- [How do I troubleshoot a Windows 7 freeze or slowness?](https://superuser.com/questions/26862/how-do-i-troubleshoot-a-windows-7-freeze-or-slowness)
- [Why does WMI Provider Host (WmiPrvSE.exe) keep spiking my CPU?](https://superuser.com/questions/240794/why-does-wmi-provider-host-wmiprvse-exe-keep-spiking-my-cpu)
- [How to deal with a misbehaving dllhost.exe?](https://superuser.com/questions/548685/how-to-deal-with-a-misbehaving-dllhost-exe)

Comment: All what you've said about Process Hacker is already in ProcExp. I've done these steps first of all, and I've done my research in this way. But without result. That's why I asked this question :)

Comment: I've already checked my PC with Kaspersky IS 2013(with latest bases). No result! Let it not be a reclame, but I don't trust Avira. Because once I created a simple "virus" and it couldn't catch it. It caught it only when I renamed it to "winlogon.exe" and forgot about it when I re-renamed it to "asd.exe" =)

Comment: You should describe in you post what you already did, cause we can't know. So what steps did you take to resolve the problem ? Did you try to find a solution at Microsoft site  ? Have you downloaded the last updates from Microsoft ? Does your computer run faster when you stop these two processes ? Have you tried the link i provided: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1157

Comment: OK, I'll try to update my windows, it seems to be the only way right now... I haven't found anything in Microsoft site. I googled a lot and found nothing for Win8... Also if I stop that processes, PC runs fast. Also your link couldn't help me, because it was for WinXP SP3.

Comment: If there is a update for Windows 8 then you should update. If it does not get better, download and run **HiJackThis**:http://www.trendsecure.com/portal/en-US/_download/HiJackThis.exe then post the log here. It'll give us a decent idea of whats running and what could be hogging all your memory/cpu.