# How to determine what is running in DLLHOST.EXE that's missing /ProcessID switch?

Tags: windows, command-line, security, virus, process

I have multiple `dllhost.exe` processes running on my Windows 7 computer:
[image]

Every one of these image's command line is missing (what I am thinking is) the requisite `/ProcessID:{000000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000000}` command line option:
[image]

### Question: How can I determine what's *actually* running in this process?

*It's my belief that if I can identify the actual application doing the work inside these `dllhost.exe` processes I'll be able to determine if my system is infected or not (see below).*

---

**Why I'm Asking/What I've Tried:**

These `DLLHOST.EXE` instances look suspicious to me.  For example, several of them have a lot of open TCP/IP connections:

[image]

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) shows and *absurd* amount of activity. Just one of these processes generated 124,390 events in under 3 minutes. To make matters worse, several of these `dllhost.exe` processes are writing approximately 280 MB of data *per minute* to the user's `TEMP` and `Temporary Internet Files` folders in the form of folders and files with random four character names. Some of these are in use and cannot be deleted.   Here's a filtered sample:

[image]

**I know this is probably malicious.** Unfortunately, blasting the system from orbit must only be done after exhausting all other options.  To that point, I've done:

1. [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/antimalware/) full scan
2. [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download) full scan
3. Thoroughly reviewed [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and submitted files I don't recognize to [VirusTotal.com](http://VirusTotal.com)
4. Thoroughly reviewed [HijackThis](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/hijackthis/)
5. [TDSSKiller](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/tdsskiller/) scan
6. Reviewed [this](https://superuser.com/questions/548685/how-to-deal-with-a-misbehaving-dllhost-exe) SuperUser question
7. Followed these instructions: [How To Determine Which Application Is Running Within a COM+ or Transaction Server Package](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/290884/EN-US?wa=wsignin1.0)
8. For each of the `DLLHOST.EXE` processes, I've reviewed the *DLLs* and *Handles* view in Process Explorer for any `.exe`, `.dll` or other application-type files for anything suspicious. Everything checked out though.
9. Ran [ESET Online scanner](http://eset.com/us/online-scanner)
10. Ran Microsoft [Safety Scanner](http://www.microsoft.com/security/scanner/en-us/default.aspx)
11. Booted to Safe Mode.  The command switch-less `dllhost.exe` instance is still running.

And aside from a few minor adware detections, nothing malicious is popping up!

---

**Update 1**
`<<Removed as irrelevant>>`

**Update 2**
Results of `SFC /SCANNOW`:
[image]

Comment: ask this Gov Maharaj from Microsoft via the posted emai, so that he can answer this in his show: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/

Comment: @harrymc Mine shows **7/13/2009** and 7168 bytes. File version 6.1.7600.16385.

Comment: If your Windows is 64-bit then I would guess that the problem is coming from a 32-bit installed product.

Comment: What's on the strings tab? Anything interesting?

Comment: Could be worthwhile to know what of _services_ the `dllhost.exe` process makes use of? Start from command line `wmic path Win32_Service Where "ProcessId = 28420"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see on my computer dllhost.exe running from `C:\Windows\System32`, while yours is running from
`C:\Windows\SysWOW64`, which looks somewhat suspicious. But the problem can still be caused
by some 32-bit product installed on your computer.
Check also the Event Viewer and post here any suspicious messages.

My guess is that you are infected or that Windows has become very unstable.

The first step is to see whether the problem arrives when booting into Safe mode.
If it doesn't arrive there, then the problem is (maybe) with some installed product.

If the problem does arrive in Safe mode, then the problem is with Windows.
Try running [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html) to verify system integrity.

If no problems are found, scan using :

- [AdwCleaner](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/)
- [ComboFix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/)

If nothing helps, try a boot-time antivirus such as :

- [Dr.Web](http://www.freedrweb.com/livedisk)
- [F-Secure](http://www.f-secure.com/en/web/labs_global/rescue-cd)
- [Panda](http://www.pandasecurity.com/usa/homeusers/support/card/?id=80152)

To avoid burning real CDs,
use [Windows 7 USB DVD Download Tool](http://wudt.codeplex.com/) to install the ISOs one-by-one
on a USB key to boot from.

If all fails and you do suspect an infection,
the safest solution is to format the disk and reinstall Windows,
but try all other possibilities first.

Comment: There are some steps here I'll begin trying.  The machine is well-maintained and has been stable until this behavior showed up (we were alerted to the problem by 10 GB of temp files written in a few days' time).  I think the file being in `\SysWOW64` is OK as I've confirmed the same file exists on other Win7 machines.

Comment: If you suspect an installed startup product, [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) is a handy utility for turning them off in bunches and then back on again, rebooting each time.

Comment: I've repeatedly and extensively examined the Autoruns entries and found nothing suspicious. What gets me is this behavior showed up out of the blue.

Comment: What did you find in the 10GB Temp folder?

Comment: Thousands of folders with 4 character names and random files in them.  Since the call for help was due to `C:` being out of disk space, once I found that much temp data I did what a good tech does and deleted it.  It was only after noticing how rapidly the disk space went down that I started suspecting something out of the ordinary.

Comment: If it's still happening, you could use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to find out the writing process. Or is it dllhost.exe?

Comment: I did run ProcMon and the data was coming from `dllhost.exe`. The screenshot in my question shows only the `Temporary Internet Files` location, but it included the `%TEMP%` folder as well.

Comment: Was there any maintenance done lately such as updating an installed product or Windows Update (the most dangerous of all)? You could try a system restore back to an earlier date. See also this [Mark Russinovich blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/09/24/3126858.aspx?PageIndex=5) on how to analyze a dllhost.exe problem. But if it's really an infection all you can do is run every antivirus under the sun and if they all fail nuke the computer (which is always the safest).

Comment: LOL. I in fact chided the user for not having recently installed updates...it looked as though he hadn't installed the latest round of Patch Tuesday updates.  Breaking news here...ComboFix detects `Poweliks` malware...which I've had my eye on as a possible culprit, although this is the first positive detection on the system.

Comment: If it's Poweliks then your user isn't very careful about opening email attachments. Even if eradicated, scan again with several well-known antivirus products in case it brought in some friends. And fully patch his computer including all installed applications.

Comment: -1 This does not answer the question. This should be a comment.

Comment: @kinokijuf: Thanks for leaving a comment justifying the downvote. To my defense I note that this is the accepted answer, since an antivirus I recommended found the infection when many others failed.

Answer (score 9):

## It's a Fileless, Memory-Injecting, DLL Trojan!

*The credit for pointing me in the right direction goes to @harrymc so I've awarded him the answer flag & bounty.*

As far as I can tell, a proper instance of `DLLHOST.EXE` always has the `/ProcessID:` switch.  These processes don't because **they're executing a .DLL that has been injected directly into memory by the [Poweliks trojan](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2461120/stealthy-malware-poweliks-resides-only-in-system-registry.html).**

According to [this writeup](http://www.adlice.com/poweliks-removal-with-roguekiller/):

> ...[Poweliks] is stored in an encrypted registry value, and loaded at boot time by a RUN key calling rundll32 process on an encrypted JavaScript payload.
>
> Once [the] payload [is] loaded in rundll32, it tries to execute an embedded PowerShell script in interactive mode (no UI). That PowerShell scripts contains a base64-encoded payload (another one) which will be injected into a dllhost process (the persistent item), which will be zombified and act as a trojan downloader for other infections.

As noted in at the beginning of the above-referenced article, recent variants (mine included) no longer start from an entry in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\...\RUN` key but are instead hidden in a hijacked CLSID key.  And to make it even harder to detect there are [no files written to disk](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2461120/stealthy-malware-poweliks-resides-only-in-system-registry.html), only these Registry entries.

Indeed (thanks to harrymc's suggestion) I found the trojan by doing the following:

1. Boot to Safe Mode
2. Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to suspend all of the rouge `dllhost.exe` processes
3. Run a [ComboFix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/) scan

In my case the Poweliks trojan was hiding in the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{AB8902B4-09CA-4bb6-B78D-A8F59079A8D5}` key (which is has to do with the Thumbnail Cache).  Apparently when this key is accessed it executes the trojan.  Since thumbnails are used a lot this had the effect of the trojan coming to life almost as quickly as if it had an actual `RUN` entry in the Registry.

For some additional technical details, see this TrendMicro [blog post](http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/poweliks-malware-hides-in-windows-registry/).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do these kind of forensic analyst of running processes, services, network connection, ... I recommend you to use also [ESET SysInspector.](http://www.eset.com/int/download/utilities/detail/family/3/)  It gives you better view about running files, also you can see not only dllhost.exe, but files linked with argument for this file, path for auto startup programs, ... Some of them may be services, it also take their names, you see it in nice colorized application.

One big advance is that it also give you AV results for all files listed in log, so if you have infected system, there is a big chance to find a source. You can also post here xml log and we can check it.
Of course, SysInspector is part of ESET AV in Tools tab.

Comment: I installed and ran ESET SysInspector but it's not telling me anything Process Explorer and Process Monitor haven't told me so far, although I do like how SysInspector makes some of this information easier to access.