# dllhost.exe COM surrogate

Tags: windows-7, memory

Okay, I didn't know why this is happen, but when I do the usual task with my laptop, like surfing on the internet, and open windows explorer, firefox. At that time my used ram was 45% to 55%, but suddenly it goes to 90%, I opened the task manager and found dllhost.exe which is seems peculiar to me, because I myself often check my taskmanager and not sure that I have this exe, and the surprise thing is, it used 2gb of my memory, which I absolutely sure that this is the root of the problem. I click end process, and ignore the warning, and my consumed ram back to normal, I don't know why this is happen, and is my action isn't wrong for solving this? At this time, I haven't reboot my computer yet, I'm not sure if this is happen again.

Comment: Look at this [question](http://superuser.com/q/833914/213131) and see if it helps you.

Comment: which 3rd party Audio/Video codecs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec) do you have installed? This exe creates thumbnails of videos, so a bad codec can cause the leak.

Answer (score 0):

COM surrogate process might affect your CPU and RAM because the exe file is corrupted or possibly related to malware. Try an anti-malware program, it can detect infection and get rid of it. EXE files are used to disguise malicious programs because of the fact that they are commonly found working in the background. Try finding related malware. Or check for outdated drivers manually or with safe driver update software.